# Set up sub grid when creating a record

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I've added a sub grid in the Incident form, it shows the KB Articles that have the same Classification of the Incident.

It's working well when I open an existing Incident, however it doesn't work when creating a new Incident.

In the sub grid is "**to enable this content, save the record**"

I expect this behavior when the records are related, however I'm doing a query and setting up the sub grid.

So, my requirement is to enable and be able to set up the subgrid when creating an Incident before it's saved.

Even more, when saving the record fails because a plugin stops it, the subgrid is working as expected when the Classification is changed, not being the Incident saved.

```
function Form_OnLoad() {
   ...
   if (formType == "1") { ...}
   else
   {
      //Check if there is/are article(s) with the same subject of the case
      check_articles();
   }



function check_articles()
{
  var KBArtGrid = document.getElementById('grid_kb_articles');

if (KBArtGrid == null) { //make sure the grid has loaded 
    setTimeout(function () { check_articles(); }, 500); //if the grid hasn’t loaded run this again when it has 
    return;
}

var classificationValue = new Array();
classificationValue = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("subjectid").getValue();

if(classificationValue != null && classificationValue[0] != null) {

var fetchXml = "<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>" +
"  <entity name='kbarticle'>" +
"    <attribute name='number' />" +
"    <attribute name='title' />" +
"    <attribute name='statecode' />" +
"    <attribute name='kbarticletemplateid' />" +
"    <order attribute='number' descending='false' />" +
"    <filter type='and'>" +
"      <condition attribute='subjectidname' operator='like' value='" + '%' +classificationValue[0].name +'%'+ "' />" +
"    </filter>" +
"    </entity>" +
"    </fetch>";

KBArtGrid.control.SetParameter("fetchXml", fetchXml);
KBArtGrid.control.Refresh();
```

Comment: the question is "I want to enable the subgrid when creating a new incident"? the reply is "you can't with supported customizations." Maybe there is a way with unsupported one, but please explain your requirement in your question :)

Comment: You could use an html web resource to list the KB articles.

Comment: I would like to have it in a subgrid, I don't see a web design on it.

Comment: What @GuidoPreite said. That's how subgrids work.

Comment: Yes, that's true, I think that I know how grids works, is suppose just to show relationships between two entities, so until I don't save the record can't show anything, HOWEVER I can fetch the subgrid  and see the rows on it when I try to save and I get a plugin exception, so the record isn't save, so that's why I think there is an internal CRM check of the FormType, or some similar. Still haven't found a way to do that initial..hacking?

Answer (score 0):

I have not try this but I think you can actually link it by mapping the field by having a customize field from both entity.

The reason behind that causing fail is because the GUID for the incident haven't created yet before save the incident therefore the KB article do not have the GUID to have the relationship.

You can pre-save the incident before saving it and pass the GUID to the KB to store it. Or using the mapping that mentioned above. With this you may need to store the references data in KB as well.